# Android ImageView and OnTouchListener finger move

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

i'm very new to Android SDK, so excuse my silly question.
I made a simple app with an ImageView set as background    android:background="@drawable/image"
 and i added two zoom buttons, so i can zoom in and out the picture that is on the whole screen.So my question is should i use OnTouchListener or is there a better way to just move the picture view up,down, left or right with my finger, i just need these basic events, nothing else.
I'm added part of my code, if anyone advises me, where would be better to implement it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_map);

        zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        startX = img.getScaleX();
        startY = img.getScaleY();

        zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                float x = img.getScaleX();
                float y = img.getScaleY();

                img.setScaleX((float) (x+1));
                img.setScaleY((float) (y+1));                   
            }
        });

        zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                float x = img.getScaleX();
                float y = img.getScaleY();
                if((x>startX) & (y>startY)) {
                    img.setScaleX((float) (x-1));
                    img.setScaleY((float) (y-1));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Is it best to use OnTouchListener ?

Comment: Ya it is best way to use **OnTouchListener** for ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a good way to implement the movement of ***OnTouchListener*** for ImageView.

you can go through here

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Touch_and_Multi-touch_Event_Handling

http://www.mysecretroom.com/www/programming-and-software/android-multi-touch-handling

http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/listview/android-multitouch-listview-example/

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html